# java spring 4 hibernate 5 two entity manager contexts error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have the following spring xml configuration:

```
  <bean id="entityManagerFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/astra_persistence.xml" />
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit1" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="astraDataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="astraJpaVendorAdapter" />
            <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
  </bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory2" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" primary="true">
            <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit2" />
            <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
            <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />

            <property name="jpaProperties">
                <props>
                    <prop key="hibernate.physical_naming_strategy">com.mypackage.domain.jpa.model.naming.ImprovedPhysicalNamingStrategy</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy">org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl</prop>
                </props>
            </property>

            <property name="packagesToScan"
                      value="com.mypackage" />
</bean>
```

In my DAO:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit2")
protected EntityManager myEntityManager;
```

And I can't set it up because of the following error:

```
NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined
```

I tried:

1. primary="true"  in xml config - no luck
2. **unitName** instead of **name** in **@PersistenceContext** - no luck

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to qialify your Em with appropriate name

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory2")
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistenceUnit2")
protected EntityManager myEntityManager;
```